# How to accurately center a TextField in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to center a text field on a sprite.
I have read answers regarding this issue. Supposedly, the solution is to proceed like this :

```
textField.x = sprite.width/2 - textField.textWidth/2;
textField.y = sprite.height/2 - textField.textHeight/2;
```

I have tried it and it "kind of" works but the result is really inaccurate in my opinion.
Here is what I get with the following code :

[image: bad centering]

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Shape;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class MainTest extends Sprite
    {
        public function MainTest()
        {   
            var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var background:Shape = new Shape();
            background.graphics.beginFill(0xAAAAAA);
            background.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 20);
            background.graphics.endFill();
            sprite.addChild(background);
            var tf:TextField = new TextField();
            tf.text = "Test";
            tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            sprite.addChild(tf);
            stage.addChild(sprite);
            tf.x = sprite.width/2 - tf.textWidth/2;
            tf.y = sprite.height/2 - tf.textHeight/2;
            sprite.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - sprite.width / 2;
            sprite.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - sprite.height / 2;
        }
    }

}
```

The gap on the left is too big and the this is definitely not vertically centered!
Do you get the same result? Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.width` and `tf.height` rather than `textWidth` and `textHeight`. The latter don't take into account the padding/margins etc.

This images from `TextLineMetrics` shows the difference:

[image: TextLineMetrics showing the difference between textWidth/textHeight and width/height]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered *not* using `TextFieldAutoSize` and instead simply use the in built align methods built into `TextFormat`?

```
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textFormat.align = "center";

tf.setTextFormat(textFormat);
```

Alternatively, have you checked out `TextFieldAutoSize.CENTER`?

Comment: None of the above worked for me... The results are even worse...
Do you get better results on your computer?

Comment: @user3240131 When aligning in the center you shouldn't use auto size at all **and** you should make sure you specify a text field width.